# How to efficiently find overlapping intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, overlap

I have the following toy example dataframe, `df`:

```
      f_low    f_high
   0.476201  0.481915
   0.479161  0.484977
   0.485997  0.491911
   0.503259  0.508679
   0.504687  0.510075
   0.504687  0.670075
   0.666093  0.670438
   0.765602  0.770028
   0.766884  0.771307
   0.775986  0.780398
   0.794590  0.798965
```

to find overlapping subsets of this, I am using the following code:

```
df = df.sort_values('f_low')
for row in df.itertuples():
    iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.f_low, df.f_high, closed='neither')
    span_range = pd.Interval(row.f_low, row.f_high)
    fx = df[(iix.overlaps(span_range))].copy()
```

I would LIKE to get overlapping dataframes like this:

```
   # iteration 1: over row.f_low=0.476201  row.f_high=0.481915 

      f_low    f_high
   0.476201  0.481915
   0.479161  0.484977

   # iteration 2: over row.f_low=0.503259  row.f_high=0.508679 
      f_low    f_high
   0.503259  0.508679 
   0.504687  0.510075
   0.504687 0.670075

   # iteration 3: over row.f_low=0.504687  row.f_high=0.670075 
      f_low    f_high
   0.666093  0.670438
```

etc.

This works great, but since the dataframe is quite large and there are a lot of overlaps, this takes a long time to process. Also, the interval I am testing for overlaps does not grab itself when using the `Interval` and `overlaps` methods for pandas.

What this is meant to represent is a series of overlapping confidence intervals with each row that gets iterated over.

Is there a way to more efficiently extract overlapping intervals against a given interval besides iterating through all the tuples?

Here is a chunk of the actual dataframe unsorted:

```
f_low   f_high
0.504687  0.670075
0.476201  0.481915
0.765602  0.770028
0.479161  0.484977
0.766884  0.771307
0.485997  0.491911
0.666093  0.670438
0.503259  0.508679
0.775986  0.780398
0.504687  0.510075
0.794590  0.798965
```

Comment: To make sure I understand. Why are the second and third subgroups separated and not a group of four consecutive overlaps ? I haven't figured out the full logic yet but I suspect the following might be a lead to explore : `df.shift(-1).f_low < df.f_high`

Comment: updating question

Comment: don't you want the dfs to include the first row?

Comment: also, is the output format multiple dfs, or something else?

Comment: re: including first row, I see the row in the comment: `# row.f_low=0.476201  row.f_high=0.481915` does not exist in the first df group.  The same is true for subsequent groups.

Comment: Yes, the rows in comments SHOULD be in the dataframe groups, and yes, multiple dataframes are desirable to distinguish between different overlapping CIs.

Comment: okay, sorry... more updating. got confused.

Comment: The last row of the second group (which happens to be the first row of the last group as well) overlaps with the second row of the last group. Why are they not a single group ? Why is the last group singled out ?

Comment: @ApplePie as I understand it, the range is set by the first row in the group.  In that case, the third group is malformed

Comment: @horcle_buzz I think you should take a look at the other solution :)

Comment: @anon01, I'm looking at it. There seems to be a problem with `idx` being 0 ... you are correct, btw about the third group being malformed.

Comment: solution updated

Comment: thanks! need to test out these methods tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to separate your current df into data frames where the initial interval is set by the first row, and the second interval is defined by the first row that does not intersect, etc.  The below method will do that and should be pretty efficient if the number of groups isn't too large:

```
df = df.sort_values("f_low").reset_index(drop=True)
idx = 0
dfs = []
while True:
    low = df.f_low[idx]
    high = df.f_high[idx]
    sub_df = df[(df.f_low <= high) & (low <= df.f_low)]
    dfs.append(sub_df)
    idx = sub_df.index.max() + 1
    if idx > df.index.max():
        break
```

output:

```
[      f_low    f_high
 0  0.476201  0.481915
 1  0.479161  0.484977,
       f_low    f_high
 2  0.485997  0.491911,
       f_low    f_high
 3  0.503259  0.508679
 4  0.504687  0.510075
 5  0.504687  0.670075,
       f_low    f_high
 6  0.666093  0.670438,
       f_low    f_high
 7  0.765602  0.770028
 8  0.766884  0.771307,
       f_low    f_high
 9  0.775986  0.780398,
       f_low    f_high
 10  0.79459  0.798965]
```

Comment: your actual data frame looks unsorted, but that was not true for the example df.  Please provide one df that represents your data.  I will add a sort to the solution.

Comment: Nice! While all the other solutions have their redeemable and unique variants, this one actually does exactly what I need (I think@piRSquared's is pretty usable, too). My dataframe is large, but not so much so that performance is affected using this solution. I might do some timing experiments later, after I get my analysis under wraps.

Answer (score 4):

### Continuous Overlap

Treat `"f_low"` values as entry points and assign a value of `1`.  Treat `"f_high"` values as exit points and assign a value of `-1`.  If we proceed through all values in increasing order and accumulate assigned values then we will have an overlapping interval when the accumulated value is greater than zero.  We know we've exited any overlapping intervals if the accumulated value reaches zero.

NOTE:

This groups all intervals that continuously overlap.  If an interval doesn't overlap with the first ***BUT*** does overlap with the last one in the chain, then it counts as overlapping.

I'll provide an analogous solution for the other option below this solution.

---

#### Attempted Example

```
#  1     3                     (Interval from 1 to 3)
#     2        5               (Interval from 2 to 5)
#                    7     9   (Interval from 7 to 9)

#  1  1 -1    -1     1    -1   (Entry/Exit values)
#  1  2  1     0     1     0   (Accumulated values)
#              ⇑           ⇑
# zero indicates leaving all overlaps
```

This indicates that we start once we enter into the interval from `1` to `3`, we don't leave all overlapping intervals until we get to `5` the right side of the interval from `2` to `5` as indicate by the accumulated value reaching zero.

---

I'll use a generator to return lists of the indices of the original dataframe that have overlapping intervals.

When all is said and done, this should be `N * Log(N)` for the sorting involved.

```
def gen_overlaps(df):
    df = df.sort_values('f_low')
    
    # get sorter lows and highs
    a = df.to_numpy().ravel().argsort()
    
    # get free un-sorter
    b = np.empty_like(a)
    b[a] = np.arange(len(a))
    
    # get ones and negative ones
    # to indicate entering into
    # and exiting an interval
    c = np.ones(df.shape, int) * [1, -1]
    
    # if we sort by all values and
    # accumulate when we enter and exit
    # the accumulated value should be 
    # zero when there are no overlaps
    d = c.ravel()[a].cumsum()[b].reshape(df.shape)
    #             ⇑           ⇑
    # sort by value order     unsort to get back to original order
    
    indices = []
    for i, indicator in zip(df.index, d[:, 1] == 0):
        indices.append(i)
        if indicator:
            yield indices
            indices = []
    if indices:
        yield indices
```

Then I'll use `pd.concat` to organize them to show what I mean.  `k` is the `kth` group.  Some groups only have one interval.

```
pd.concat({
    k: df.loc[i] for k, i in
    enumerate(gen_overlaps(df))
})

         f_low    f_high
0 0   0.476201  0.481915
  1   0.479161  0.484977
1 2   0.485997  0.491911
2 3   0.503259  0.508679
  4   0.504687  0.510075
  5   0.504687  0.670075
  6   0.666093  0.670438
3 7   0.765602  0.770028
  8   0.766884  0.771307
4 9   0.775986  0.780398
5 10  0.794590  0.798965
```

If we only wanted the ones that overlapped...

```
pd.concat({
    k: df.loc[i] for k, i in
    enumerate(gen_overlaps(df))
    if len(i) > 1
})

        f_low    f_high
0 0  0.476201  0.481915
  1  0.479161  0.484977
2 3  0.503259  0.508679
  4  0.504687  0.510075
  5  0.504687  0.670075
  6  0.666093  0.670438
3 7  0.765602  0.770028
  8  0.766884  0.771307
```

---

### Only Overlap Next Interval in Queue

This is a simpler solution and matches OPs desired output.

```
def gen_overlaps(df):
    df = df.sort_values('f_low')
        
    indices = []
    cursor = None
    for i, low, high in df.itertuples():
        if not indices:
            cursor = high
        if low <= cursor:
            indices.append(i)
        else:
            yield indices
            indices = []
            cursor = high
    if len(indices) > 1:
        yield indices
    

pd.concat({
    k: df.loc[i] for k, i in
    enumerate(gen_overlaps(df))
})

        f_low    f_high
0 0  0.476201  0.481915
  1  0.479161  0.484977
1 3  0.503259  0.508679
  4  0.504687  0.510075
  5  0.504687  0.670075
2 7  0.765602  0.770028
  8  0.766884  0.771307
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
intervals = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Interval(row['f_low'], row['f_high']), axis=1)
overlaps = [
    (i, j, x, y, x.overlaps(y)) 
    for ((i,x),(j,y))
    in itertools.product(enumerate(intervals), repeat=2)
]

>>> overlaps[:3]
[(0,
  0,
  Interval(0.47620100000000004, 0.481915, closed='right'),
  Interval(0.47620100000000004, 0.481915, closed='right'),
  True),
 (0,
  1,
  Interval(0.47620100000000004, 0.481915, closed='right'),
  Interval(0.47916099999999995, 0.48497700000000005, closed='right'),
  True),
 (0,
  2,
  Interval(0.47620100000000004, 0.481915, closed='right'),
  Interval(0.485997, 0.491911, closed='right'),
  False)]
```

From this you can get the numeric indices in the original DataFrame. Not sure how performant it is, but it should be better than what you've got now.

Comment: Nice! I'll have to play around with this, but on first impression it seems to be doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy's array broadcasting:

```py
l1 = df['f_low'].to_numpy()
h1 = df['f_high'].to_numpy()

l2 = l1[:, None]
h2 = h1[:, None]

# Check for overlap
# mask is an n * n matrix indicating if interval i overlaps with interval j
mask = (l1 < h2) & (h1 > l2)

# If interval i overlaps intervla j then j also overlaps i. We only want to get
# one of the two pairs. Hence the `triu` (triangle, upper)
# Every interval also overlaps itself and we don't want that either. Hence the k=1
overlaps = np.triu(mask, k=1).nonzero()
```

The result in `overlaps` requires some interpretations:

```py
(array([0, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7]),
 array([1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8]))

# Row 0 overlaps with row 1
# Row 3 overlaps with row 4
# Row 3 overlaps with row 5
# ....
```

Comment: this will scale as n^2 in memory, no?

Comment: Yes. It memory becomes a problem you can use `np.packbits` to reduce the ndarray to 1/8th its size. Or you can work in smaller chunks to reduce the memory footprint

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of overlapping do you need, but I think this approach can work for it:

- To make sure your masking is adequate.
- Create a dictionary which keys are f_low and f_high from every iteration.
- Filter the original dataframe
- As you said, the real use case should be with a large datasets, so `query` must be better than `.loc`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0.504687, 0.670075],
        [0.476201, 0.481915],
        [0.765602, 0.770028],
        [0.479161, 0.484977],
        [0.766884, 0.771307],
        [0.485997, 0.491911],
        [0.666093, 0.670438],
        [0.503259, 0.508679],
        [0.775986, 0.780398],
        [0.504687, 0.510075],
        [0.794590, 0.798965]
    ],
    columns=["f_low", "f_high"]
)
overlap = {
    (row.f_low, row.f_high): df.query("(@row.f_low <= f_low <= @row.f_high) or (@row.f_low <= f_high <= @row.f_high)")
    for row in df.itertuples()
}
```